# Parsing JSON data between AJAX and php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, validation

So I am running into an issue with my project. I have two files im running which are `admin.php` and `register.php` . When I run these files locally I get no issues. Basically I validate the form in my admin file which returns JSON data to the register file. The only issue is, when I run my project on a VPS my register page no longer reads exported JSON data from my admin page and I can't figure out why.

**Below are snipets of code** | Admin.php

```php
    $status = array("status"=>2,"msg"=>"Email already exist.");
    return json_encode($status, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    exit;
```

Register.php

```php
           $.ajax({
                url:'./chat/ajax.php?action=create_account',
                data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                method: 'POST',
                type: 'POST',
                error:err=>{
                    console.log(err)
                },
                success:function(resp){
                    resp = JSON.parse(resp)
                    var newdata = data.status;
                    console.log(resp);
                    if(newdata == 1){
                            location.replace('login.php')
                    }else{
                        console.log(resp[status]);
                        $('#msg').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Caught Error</div>")
                        end_load()
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: What happens then? The entire data is missing? Maybe it is a matter of whitelist on the server? Or is the information there but correct?

Comment: How is `Admin.php` tied to this AJAX that calls `/chat/ajax.php`?

Comment: @El_Vanja The admin.php runs functions from my ajax file

Comment: And where are you actually echoing any response back to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try echo on admin.php like below code

```
$status = array("status"=>2,"msg"=>"Email already exist.");
echo json_encode($status, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's due to lack of **php json extension** in the vps that you're using. Install this extension. You can see https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php for more info